# How to get this result with aggregate in R

Tags: r, aggregate

A small but useful sample as follows:

```
df=read.table(text="class time
        a 12
        a  11
        a 11
        b 15
        b 10
        c 14
        c 11
        ",header=TRUE)
```

I want to get the median for a and b together, this gives me a  value of 11.

My effort is:

```
aggergate(time~class, data=df, median)
```

Comment: If you simply want the median as a scalar value (here `11`), simply subscripting should do the trick: `median(df[df$class %in% c("a", "b"), "time"])`. For more advanced filtrations and aggregations, packages like `dplyr` (more intuitive) or `data.table` (higher performance) should come in handy. However, if you're getting stuck on this, I'd recommend examining the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/aggregate) in greater depth.

Answer (score 1):

I realise you asked specifically for a solution using `aggregate`, but there are a few ways to solve this problem that I find easier than using `aggregate`. The first, as Greg already suggested, would be something like:

```
median(df$time[df$class %in% c("a", "b")])

[1] 11
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to use a tidyverse approach, you could do:

```
library(tidyverse)
filter(df, class %in% c("a", "b")) %>% summarise(median(time))

  median(time)
1           11
```